# Amadeus API - java.lang Exception

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, amadeus

I'm having a problem with implementing the Amadeus API in Android Studio.
This is my first Android App, so this is my first time using AsyncTask etc.

Here is my crash report:

As you can see this single crash line sticks out:

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2017-07-06"

From the log: the api is doing its job, but somehow at the end crashes because of an input string exception.

noman.places.example I/tag: {

> ```
>                                                          "origin" : "FRA",
>                                                          "currency" : "EUR",
>                                                          "results" : [ {
>                                                            "destination" : "LON",
>                                                            "departure_date" : "2017-07-06",
>                                                            "return_date" : "2017-07-07",
>                                                            "price" : "258.87",
>                                                            "airline" : "BA"
>                                                          } ]
>                                                        }
>
>                                                        --------- beginning of crash 06-05 00:46:59.142 18633-18652/noman.places.example
> ```
>
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>                                                                         Process: noman.places.example, PID: 18633
>                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
>                                                                             at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
>                                                                             at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                             at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
>   "2017-07-06"
>                                                                             at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:443)
>                                                                             at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:485)
>                                                                             at com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive.getAsLong(JsonPrimitive.java:238)
>                                                                             at io.swagger.client.JsonUtil$1.deserialize(JsonUtil.java:37)
>                                                                             at io.swagger.client.JsonUtil$1.deserialize(JsonUtil.java:35)
>                                                                             at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)
>                                                                             at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:103)
>                                                                             at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
>                                                                             at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
>                                                                             at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
>                                                                             at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
>                                                                             at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:103)
>                                                                             at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
>                                                                             at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
>                                                                             at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
>                                                                             at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
>                                                                             at io.swagger.client.JsonUtil.deserializeToObject(JsonUtil.java:55)
>                                                                             at io.swagger.client.ApiInvoker.deserialize(ApiInvoker.java:256)
>                                                                             at
>   io.swagger.client.api.DefaultApi.flightInspirationSearch(DefaultApi.java:1085)
>                                                                             at
>   noman.places.example.MapsActivity$AmadeusTask.doInBackground(MapsActivity.java:144)
>                                                                             at
>   noman.places.example.MapsActivity$AmadeusTask.doInBackground(MapsActivity.java:125)
>                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
>                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
>                                                                             at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                                                                             at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Here is my implementation of the API:

```
private class AmadeusTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... task) {
            DefaultApi apiInstance = new DefaultApi();
            String apikey = "AkEzmf5bDGatkBld2PNjJfvRna3hHbZP";
            String org = "FRA";
            String dest = "LON";
            String depDate = "2017-07-06";
            Boolean oneWay = false;
            String duration = "1";
            Boolean direct = true;
            String maxPrice = "1000";
            String lat = "46.6734";
            String lon = "-71.7412";

            try {
                ExtremeSearchResponse test = apiInstance.flightInspirationSearch(apikey, org, dest,depDate,oneWay,duration,direct,maxPrice,"DAY");
            }   catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;}

   protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
    }
}
```

If anyboy could tell me that this is not a bug within API, but rather a problem
with the Async Task Implementation, I would be pleased.

Comment: *Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2017-07-06"* - what number do you think it should be convertd to ?

Comment: Don't really know. Will need to find out though...some function within the API which converts the date. The API documentation clearly states though that the API call of the date should be in this form. YYYY-MM-DD